# Как изменить язык во всем приложение?

Tags: vue.js, framework7

пишу приложение на vue + framework и для локализации использую i18n, как можно реализовать, чтобы смена языка происходила на всех страницах и оставалась?

Answer (score 0):

Если пользователь авторизован, то писать текущую локаль в базу и дергать эти данные вместе с пользовательскими полями, т.е небольшой функционал API реализовать.

Если не авторизован, то локаль нужно хранить либо на клиенте localStoraje или indexedDB или сервер php сессии + cokie